# Converting hours to acceptable FME format?

Tags: fme-form, time, transformer

I have an Excel document with a 'time' column. I need to get this column into an appropriate format for FME to convert the values to minutes. 
The problem is that the cells are in different formats (h:mm, [h]:mm:ss).

An example of the data is:

1. 1:44
2. 0:34
3. 45:44
4. 223:44

I.e 223 hours and 44 minutes needs to read 13424 minutes.

Any advice on transforming these values?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't played around with time calculations much in FME. However, you could split the string and extract the portion left of the colon and multiply by 60 and add the right hand portion.

To do that, I suggest using an [AttributeSplitter](https://docs.safe.com/fme/2018.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/attributesplitter.htm) with the colon as the delimiter. This will store the results into a list attribute which you can manipulate as you need.

Alternatively, you could use a [PythonCaller](https://docs.safe.com/fme/2018.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/pythoncaller.htm?Highlight=pythoncaller) and split the attribute using Python and do all your work there.

You may have some luck with the [DateTimeConverter](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/datetimecalculator.htm). I haven't tried it for this purpose, though.

Comment: I'm going to make some suggestions to our developers around this. The DateTimeConverter doesn't work because it expects time to be an absolute (ie a particular time of day) not a period of time like x hours. I thought the repair overlap part might help, but alas not. So I think your current solution is the best one for now, but I think we could do better.

Answer (score 1):

First format the entire column to Custom Format "hh:mm:ss" so any data appearing in it takes on a singular recognisable time format.

To simply understand how excel calculates digital time values:
A day (24 hrs)= 1; an hour = 1/24, a minute = 1/1440 and a second is 1/86400

From there onwards, you may be better off with a custom program in VBA that can calculate all the correct variables for you and return the results back to you rapidly whereas in a formulaic calculation, it will really chew on your computer resources as more data is added that may possibly crash Excel in large dta calculations.

Answer (score 1):

So @Fezter's answer is good for splitting the data with the AttributeSplitter, in order to separate the hours, minutes, seconds fields.

However, instead of using the DateTimeConverter, try the DateTimeCalculator transformer. For example, you can add 223 hours and 44 minutes to midnight Jan 1, 1970 (or whatever), and then subtract midnight Jan 1, 1970 from the result, and get an answer in minutes or hours.

For the first operation you would:

With an AttributeCreator, create an attribute, Date, set to = 19700101000000 (which is midnight on Jan 1st, 1970)

[image]

Notice I'm also creating a sample time using your example.

Now with the DateTimeCalculator, set the mode to Add or Subtract Interval. Set DateTime = Date attribute, and the hours, minutes, seconds to the attributes created by the AttributeSplitter. Set the operation to Add.

For the second operation, add a second DateTimeCalculator. Set the mode to Calculate Interval Between DateTimes. Set Start DateTime = Date again, and End DateTime to the result of the previous operation (_result_datetime by default). Set the result type to be Minutes.

[image]

It's a little long-winded, but it will work:

[image]

The advantage of doing it this way is that you can change the type in the second DateTimeCalculator as required, to get seconds, minutes, hours, days, or whatever, without having to adjust any other calculations.

In the long run I've asked our developers to consider supporting time periods in the DateTimeConverter (currently it only handles absolute times) and I think we will do this for sure because it would be so useful.